# After_stat() and glue() do not work together

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, r-glue

I would like to create a plot using `plotly::ggplotly()`.  This works just fine.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.2

p <-
  mtcars |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(
      x = disp,
      text = after_stat(count)
    )
  )
#> Warning in geom_histogram(aes(x = disp, text = after_stat(count))): Ignoring
#> unknown aesthetics: text

plotly::ggplotly(p)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

There is a nice trick with `ggplotly()` that allows me to use dummy aesthetics to display in the tooltip.  Below, I use the `text` aesthetic for this purpose.  However, `glue()` doesn't work with `after_stat()`.  How can I fix this?

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.2.2

p <-
  mtcars |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(
    aes(
      x = disp,
      text = glue::glue('{after_stat(count)}')
    )
  )
#> Warning in geom_histogram(aes(x = disp, text =
#> glue::glue("{after_stat(count)}"))): Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text

plotly::ggplotly(p)
#> Error in after_stat(count): object 'count' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

It work with `text` outside `aes` (that surprises me):

```r
p <-
   ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x = disp), text = glue::glue('{after_stat({count})}')) +
   geom_histogram()
 
plotly::ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: It does work, but it doesn't display anything in the tooltip.  If I change it to `glue::glue('Bin Size = {after_stat({count})}')`, it doesn't change the tooltip.